# Understanding DNA match of 2,559cM to grandparent

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

I received my DNA results from Ancestry. My first DNA match ended up being my paternal grandpa. We shared 37 percent of our DNA and 2559cm.

If that seems high, what could be causing so strong of a match?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's on the high end for grandparent, but still in the range; according to [DNA painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2559)

0.33% chance is small, but non-zero.